# React.js refuses to notice changes

Tags: reactjs, typescript

It seems like in some cases React will not propagate state changes into child components.

**Minimum example**

I tried to boil down my observed behavior into the smallest test case I could find, but it still ended up being pretty large. Sorry about that.

```
class Inner extends React.Component<{ value: number }, { value: number }> {
  constructor(props: { value: number }) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { value: props.value };
  }

  render() {
    return <span> { this.state.value } </span>
  }
}

class Test extends React.Component<{}, { value: number }> {
  constructor(props: {}) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { value: 0 };

    setTimeout(() => { this.setState({ value: 1 }); }, 500);
  }

  render() {
    return <span>
      <Inner value={ this.state.value } />
    </span>;
  }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('somediv'));
```

**Quick summary**

Test has "value" in it's state, which is displayed passed into and displayed by it's inner component, "Inner".

Inside Test's constructor method, I set `value` on state to 0. After 500ms, I then set it to 1. I'd expect this to change Inner's display to also show a 1, since it depends on `value` from `this.state`, but it doesn't. Why not?

The *very* weird thing is that if I change the line `return <span> { this.state.value } </span>` to use `this.props.value` inside `Inner`, then it actually does update. Of course, I need to use state in my app that I distilled this example from.

I expect I am missing some fundamental part of React here. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor for `Inner` is only run once when the component instance is first created.

As a result, this is only run once, not every time the props change:

```
this.state = { value: props.value };
```

So if you pass new props into `Inner`, the value of `this.props.value` will change, but the value of `this.state.value` won't.

Right now this is what happens:

1. The timeout calls `setValue` on `Test` and updates the state of `Test`
2. React re-renders `Test`
3. As part of the rendering process `Test` passes a new prop value into `Inner`
4. `Inner` re-renders - its props have changed, but its state hasn't.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaah. Thank you. That makes things much more clear.